# How to avoid multiple async pipes with the same Observable source in Angular?

Tags: angular, rxjs

My component has an `Observable` named `state$`: how can I avoid repeat myself when I need to access `state$.favorites`, like the example below?

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  template: `
    <ng-container *ngIf="(state$ | async).favorites.length">
      {{ (state$ | async).favorites.length }}
    </ng-container>
  `,
})
export class ExampleComponent() {
  @Select(state => state.app) state$: Observable<AppState>;
}
```

Is there any way to assign it to a template variable?

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following:

```
 <ng-container *ngIf="(state$ | async) as state">
      {{ state.favorites.length }}
  </ng-container>
```

You don't need to check for .length. By doing what I did, you are checking if the observable has arrived and checking if the value is not null.

Comment: When I use `(state$ | async) as state`, will `state` variable be available in the entire template? What about visibility?